# SVG animate(move) text from point A to B while its content is changing

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

I'd like to animate(move) the **text** element from point A to B while its content is changing

**SVG** :

```
   <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  viewBox="300 160 350 150" height="80px" width="100%" xml:space="preserve">
     <text id="text_animated"  x="422" y="280" fill="white" font-size="17">
          <animate attributeName="y" from="150" to="250" begin="3s" dur="5.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
      </text>

<circle cx="422" cy="280" fill="red" r="5">
  <animate id="animation_depth_circle" attributeName="cy" from="150" to="250" begin="indefinite" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" onend="endAnimate()" /> 
  </circle>
</svg>
```

**JS**:

```
             var counter=0;
             var test_t = setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById('text_animated').textContent = ""+counter;

                    if(counter===120){
                        clearInterval(test_t);
                    }

                     counter=counter+1;

             },10);
```

My goal is to move the **text** (inside a **circle**) as the text is changing. The problem is that the **text** doesn't move. Only the circle does move.

btw. I can't use

```
document.getElementById('text_animated').setAttribuite('y',something);
```

because it is not synchronized with the SVG animation (if network bottleneck issues occur). I'm using Chrome.

**EDIT** :

I managed to move my text using dy as so :

```
 <text   x="422" y="280" fill="white" >
       <animate  attributeName="dy" from="0" to="250"  dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </text>
```

The problem is that It doesn't move if I change the text with my javascript. So It's either change or move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `textContent = "" + counter;` you remove the animation from inside the text element. However you can declare the animation outside the animated  element (the text in this case) and give an explicit target element for the animation by using the  `xlink:href` attribute to reference the target's id: `xlink:href="#text_animated"`.

Also you are animating the cy attribute. I prefer to use `animateTransform` and animate a translation instead

```js
var counter = 0;
var test_t = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("text_animated").textContent = "" + counter;

  if (counter === 120) {
    clearInterval(test_t);
  }

  counter = counter + 1;
}, 10);
```

```css
svg{background:black}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="350 120 150 250" width="200">
     <text id="text_animated"  x="422" y="150" fill="white" font-size="17" transform="translate(0,0)">    
      </text>
   
   <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 0,100" 
        begin="3s"
        dur="5.5s" 
        repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"
        xlink:href="#text_animated" />

<circle cx="422" cy="280" fill="red" r="5">
  <animateTransform id="animation_depth_circle"
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 0,100" 
        begin="3s"
        dur="1.5s" 
        repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
  
 </circle>
</svg>
```

Yet another solution would have been puting the text inside a tspan element `<tspan id="text_animated"></tspan>`

```js
var counter = 0;
var test_t = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("text_animated").textContent = "" + counter;

  if (counter === 120) {
    clearInterval(test_t);
  }

  counter = counter + 1;
}, 10);
```

```css
svg{background:black}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="350 120 150 250" width="200">
     <text   x="422" y="150" fill="white" font-size="17" transform="translate(0,0)"> 
        <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 0,100" 
        begin="3s"
        dur="5.5s" 
        repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"
         />
       <tspan id="text_animated"></tspan>
      </text>
   
  

<circle cx="422" cy="280" fill="red" r="5">
  <animateTransform id="animation_depth_circle"
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 0,100" 
        begin="3s"
        dur="1.5s" 
        repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
  
 </circle>
</svg>
```

I've chanved the viewBox value because I wanted to see what I am doing. You can use what you want.

Comment: brilliant, I didn't know that textContent removes animations. works like a charm